# Facebook-ios-sdk-3.1 Share image and fetch album photos for ios5 and ios6

Tags: facebook, ios5, ios6, social-networking, facebook-ios-sdk

I've integrated the FB SDK 3.1 in my ios application to support both iOS5 and iOS6.

I can successfully share an image on my FB wall for iOS6 but I'm not able to make the sharing work for iOS5.

Anyone have idea using FBsdk 3.1 how to achieve this:

1) Share image using FBsdk 3.1 for iOS5 and iOS6(Done)

2) Fetch user albums photos for both iOS5 and iOS6.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@[Max](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1621656/max): You can post photo on facebook as below...

```
[self performPublishAction:^{
        NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                       imageToShare, @"picture",
                                       Description, @"caption",
                                       FACEBOOK_ACCESS_TOKEN],@"access_token",
                                       nil];

        [FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"me/photos" parameters:params HTTPMethod:@"POST" completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
            if (!error) {
                NSLog(@"--- Post photo Result = %@",result);
            }else{
                NSLog(@"--- Error!!! :( = %@",error);
            }
        }];
 }];
```